# CopyQ (clipboard manager) Ubuntu / Mint - how to configure it to not manage images, only to manage text

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop

Just that, I want to exclude CopyQ from managing images.
As it crashes sometimes too.

I just want the text clipboard functionalities.

CopyQ web https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/

This is so easy to configure in Ditto clipboard manager...
Can't find it how to do it on Copyq.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

From CopyQ
[FAQ - Frequently Asked Questions](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) :

> **How to store only plain text?**
>
> To disallow storing HTML and rich text:
>
> - Open “Preferences” (Ctrl+P shortcut).
> - Go to “Items” tab.
> - Disable “Web” item in the list.
> - Select “Text” item.
> - Disable “Save and display HTML and rich text”.
>
> Similarly, you can also disable “Images” in the list to avoid storing
> and rendering images.
>
> Existing items won’t be affected but any data formats can be removed:
>
> - Select an item.
> - Press F4 shortcut (“Item - Show Content…” in menu).
> - Select format from list.
> - Press Delete key.

Comment: I don't want Copyq to manage images period.

This is so easy to configure in Ditto clipboard manager...
Can't find it how to do it on Copyq.

Comment: Don't you see it as above in “Preferences” ?

Comment: Are you using the Wayland window manager or X11 ?

Comment: echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

That's the output. Using Nvidia propietary driver offered by Mint Ubuntu based distro.

Comment: What do you see in Preferences > Items?

Comment: I see a lot. I unchecked the "[ ] images" item.